# How to create MySQL database programmatically using matlab

Tags: mysql, database, matlab

I am doing some data analytics using MySQL and Matlab. My program works fine if there is already an existing database present. But it doesn't work when there is not database for which I am trying to create connection. Now, what I want to do is to create a database with a fixed name if there is no database present in that name. I searched all over the internet and haven't found any option for that. May be I am missing something.

Additionally, I would like to create a table on the newly created database and store some random data on them. I can do this part. But I am stucked on the first part which is creating database programmatically using matlab.

Please note that, I have to use only matlab for this project. Any kind cooperation will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

The code example is given below -

```
%findIfFeederExists Summary of this function goes here
% finds whether there is no. of feeders are empty or not
%   Detailed explanation goes here

%Set preferences with setdbprefs.
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat', 'dataset');
setdbprefs('NullNumberRead', 'NaN');
setdbprefs('NullStringRead', 'null');

%Make connection to database.  Note that the password has been omitted.
%Using ODBC driver.
conn = database('wisedb', 'root', '');
conn.Message;
%Read data from database.

sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM joined_table';

%sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM joined_table where joined_table.`N. of Feeder` > 0';
curs =  exec(conn, sqlQuery);
curs = fetch(curs);

dbMatrix = curs.data;

[row_count, ~] = size(dbMatrix);

if (row_count >= id)
    val = dbMatrix(id, 3);
    disp(val);
    if (val.N0x2EOfFeeder > 0)
        Str = strcat('Feeder is present on the id : ', num2str(id));
        disp(Str);
        disp(dbMatrix(id, 1:end));
    else
        Str = strcat('Feeder is NOT present on the id : ', num2str(id));
        disp(Str);
    end
else
    Str = strcat('No row found for id : ', num2str(id));
    disp(Str);
end

% = exec(conn,'SELECT * FROM inventoryTable');
close(curs);

%Assign data to output variable

%Close database connection.
close(conn);

%Clear variables
clear curs conn

end
```

You can see I can connect to an existing database using ODBC. But I am not sure how I can create a new database. What can be done for this?

Comment: If you can execute any query in matlab - this should help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-database.html

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes I can execute sql query by connecting to a database. But I don't know how to create a new database. I have updated my question, please see the code.

Comment: Hmm.. something like `exec(conn, strcat('CREATE DATABASE ', dbname))`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel but the problem is that the `conn` object is referring to the connection to `wisedb` databse. How can I use a connection with another db to create new db. I am very much confused!

Comment: There is no problem creating a new DB while using an existing one. If you want to use the new DB after createing it, try `exec(conn, strcat('USE ', dbname))` - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yes that's right. But problem will occur when I don't have a db named 'wisedb'. In that case the conn object doesn't contain anything. So, what will be the approach in that cases. Suppose, I don't have any database. And I want to create a new one. In that case how can I get a conn object?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that fimilar with matlab. But if you can't find a way to connect to the server without a DB name, you can just try to workaround it using "information_schema" as DB name, which always exist in mysql.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks for the help. But I haven't found any schema name "infomation_schema" in my db.

Comment: Check typos "info**r**mation_schema". If it doesn't work - I'm out of ideas - Sorry.